# How to set data from bottom to top while chat using firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am working on firebase chat app, i designed my layout and implemented chat module successfully but, the problem is when i send text message it works fine and set text data to bottom of the collectionView but when i close my app and open it again the setting of text data mismatch and the last message comes upward.

I tried all stack overflow questions and others try's but nothing happens any change.
[image]
can't reverse data

Comment: While fetching data from your datasource, get data in DESC order. and populate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate your array in reverse order, Because when you inserting data into array you insert last message at zero index of array, so populate array in reverse order on collection view e.g Array.reverse or you can insert data in reverse order into you array, e.g insert last message on last index of array. If you've any issue let me know.

Comment: Hi, i try this but it crashes, will you please explain me more about same.

Comment: Yes sure. You can send class (Code) I'll try to check it. Did you try to find out why it crash?

Comment: could you please send me your email address so I can give you code

Comment: ali.waseem@itinsync.com

Comment: Hi Waseem I just send you a code on your email address

Comment: I replied your email. Try it and let me know if you're facing any issue. Or you can do this like
       
         func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
self.messageList.reverse()
        return self.messageList.count
    }